# Python loop code won't print with solver code, possible n problem?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a loop where i replace all the 0's in the matrix with numbers from 1-10,  but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?

```
import numpy as np

grid = [[0, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 5],
        [6, 7, 0]]

def possible(n,grid):
    for x in grid:
        if n in x:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def solve():
    global grid
    for n in grid:    
        if n == 0:
            for n in range(1,10):
                if possible(n,grid):
                    n = n                 
                    solve()
                return
            print(np.matrix(grid))



solve()
```

Comment: `for n in grid` n will always be a list (because grid is a list of lists), not a number.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest that do not use `global` if you are new, not using is much more effective way.

Secondly, in the `solve` function, you are using

```
for n in grid
```

your grid is two dimensional, so the `n` will be a list. You should also iterate over variable `n` before you check if it is 0 or not.

So simply:

```
# ...
for n in grid:
    for m in n:
        if m == 0:
            # other codes
# ...
```

Can you try to do it with this way?